# How to Append block children

Tags: python, notion-api, notion

I'm using the code example on notion doc, but it raise the 400 error
how to fix it?

**below are the code I'm using:**

```
import requests

toggle_heading = 'https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/{my_blockid}/children'

headers = {

     'Authorization': 'Bearer {my_token}',
     "accept": "application/json",
     "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
     "content-type": "application/json"
 }

r = requests.patch(toggle_heading, headers = headers)

print(r.status_code)

 ------------

 raise 400
```

the code was copy from：

https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-block-children

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

```
toggle_heading = 'https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/{my_blockid}/children'
```

{my_blockid} here is as a string, not as a variable. You need something like:

```
my_blockid = "fjhdosfjdksljf"
toggle_heading = f'https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/{my_blockid}/children'
```

Note the [fstring](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

For:

```
headers = {

     'Authorization': 'Bearer {my_token}',
     "accept": "application/json",
     "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
     "content-type": "application/json"
 }
```

Same for this part. {my_token} is a literal string, you need something like:

```
my_token = "fdklsjflkdsfjl"
headers = {

     'Authorization': f'Bearer {my_token}',
     "accept": "application/json",
     "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
     "content-type": "application/json"
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your response sir, but I have a new question how can I code the request body when I need to append a block children, there have no code example on dev doc in python

Comment: If you have a new question, please create a new question describing your problem @CopperfieldDavid